# Same browser, 2 different behaviors on 2 laptops

Tags: windows-10, firefox, browser

I have 2 laptops. One is Win 8.1 Pro another Win 10 Home
Both have Firefox latest version v88. I open same web page on both and what I see

- on Win 8.1 page opens - no advertisements.
- on Win 10 page opens, ads are all over the page. Something pops up on the bottom (in-page), etc.

Same thing with Edge.

I am wondering if this is some sort of HP bloatware that does it? Or this is windows function that can block these? The browser is the same.

The difference here, laptop that has no adds was raw OS install. The one with ads was factory OS pre-install. But the browser was installed later.
How can I get rid of these on-page ads?

Comment: Open Edge, three dots ... top right, settings, privacy and set browsing to Strict. See if that helps you.

Comment: Both Edge and Firefox support plugins, and in their supported plugins are ad blocking utilities with pretty good reputations. Personally I'd install the uBlock Origin plugin on both. Edge also has built-in filtering and blocking, though the plugin will do a better job.

Comment: @John in Edge it worked. Now I don't see in-page advertisements.

Comment: @John you were correct. My win 8.1 Firefox was in fact on "strict". I must be set this 100 years ago. Well, laptop is 9 yo. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Both Edge and Firefox support plugins. Edge also has built-in ad-block functions as well as privacy settings. I believe Firefox may as well, but I haven't used that browser recently.

Personally, I would recommend that you open the relevant plugin/add-on installation section of each browser and find and install the uBlock Origin plugin and enable it. This is one of the best plugins out there.

For the factory-setup system, I would also recommend that you go through Apps and Features and research the HP-branded software installed on the computer to see if any of these are known to load ads. Unnecessary software can be removed.

Comment: @John was correct. In my win8.1 privacy part in Firefox was set to Strict.  And in win10 - standard. As soon as I made both browsers "strict", all ads went away.  I simply did not understand effect of this setting. I thought this is about cookies but this is more. Yea, I already removed some of the soft.